# PDF editor that can write RTL text

Tags: windows, pdf

I need a PDF editor where I can add bits of text to an existing document.

The text is in Hebrew, which is a right-to-left language. I tried using Nitro Pro 9, but when I typed Hebrew text, it came out backwards. Apparently that program wasn't made to support RTL languages.

**Is there a PDF editor that supports RTL text?**

Comment: Do you have a budget for this? Do you really need an editor or would you be ok with a PDF Reader than can add text to a PDF?

Comment: Did you try [Acrobat DC](https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/acrobat.html?promoid=C12Y324S&mv=other) and [Foxit Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-reader/).

Comment: Sejda's PDF editor should support RTL text: https://www.sejda.com/pdf-editor